# how to sort list of users by score (fetching database) javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, fetch

i have db with user(name:, score:) i need to sort list by score.

code example

```
return (
        <div>
            {loading || !data ? (
                <div>loading...</div>
            ) : (
               
               <>{data["data"].map((value, index) => (
                   <div className="line">
                    <div className="name" key={index}>{value.name}</div>
                    <div className="score" key={index}>{value.points}</div>
                   </div>

               ))}</>
            )}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: An integral part of database functionality is sorting. I'm not sure how you get your data, but asking the DB to sort the data by score is where you should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sorting = (arr) => arr.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a - b;
    })
return (
    <div>
        {loading || !data ? (
            <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
           
           <>{sorting(data["data"]).map((value, index) => (
               <div className="line">
                <div className="name" key={index}>{value.name}</div>
                <div className="score" key={index}>{value.points}</div>
               </div>

           ))}</>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on the client-side, you would use the sort method of the array.

Assuming data is in this format

```
let data = [{name : 'jack', points: 1}, { name : 'jill', points:2}]
```

you can sort it as below.

**For ascending order (smallest points first)**

```
data.sort((first,second) => first.points - second.points)
```

**Do the opposite for descending order**

```
data.sort((first,second) => second.points - first.points)
```

So your code would be

```
return (
        <div>
            {loading || !data ? (
                <div>loading...</div>
            ) : (
               
               <>{data["data"].sort((first,second) => first.points - second.points).map((value, index) => (
                   <div className="line">
                    <div className="name" key={index}>{value.name}</div>
                    <div className="score" key={index}>{value.points}</div>
                   </div>
               ))}</>
            )}
        </div>
    );
```

For more details on how sorting works, check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort